# Create JSON based another JSON as key and value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have json like

```
SampJson= [
    {
        data: "50",
        cIndex: "column0",rowno:"1"
    },
    {
        data: "5",
        cIndex: "column1",rowno:"1"
    },
    {
        data: "80",
        cIndex: "column0",rowno:"2"
    },
    {
        data: "65",
        cIndex: "column1",rowno:"2"
    }
```

];

I need to create a JSON like

```
[
    {
        rowno:1,
        column0:50,
        column1:5
    },
    {
        rowno:2,
        column0:80,
        column1:65
    }
];
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: There is no JSON there. Just JavaScript objects / arrays / strings / numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just do this:

```js
sampJson = [
    {
        data: "50",
        cIndex: "column0",
        rowno: "1"
    },
    {
        data: "5",
        cIndex: "column1",
        rowno: "1"
    },
    {
        data: "80",
        cIndex: "column0",
        rowno: "2"
    },
    {
        data: "65",
        cIndex: "column1",
        rowno: "2"
    }
];

var results = [];

sampJson.forEach(function(el) {
    if (results[+el.rowno - 1] == null) {
        results[+el.rowno - 1] = new Object();
    }
    results[+el.rowno - 1].rowno = +el.rowno;
    results[+el.rowno - 1][el.cIndex] = +el.data;
});

console.log(results);
```